# Integral lattice in noncommutative Hodge theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, noncommutative-geometry, hodge-theory, dg-categories

Associated to a $DG_{\mathbb{C}}$-category, $\mathcal{C}$, we have some Hodge theoretic data - $HH_{*}(\mathcal{C})$ plays the role of Hodge cohomology and $HP$ plays the role of de Rham cohomology. Further there is a natural Hodge to de Rham spectral sequence and Hodge filtration on $HP$. If $\mathcal{C}=Perf(X)$ for some smooth projective variety, $X$, we recover a $2$-periodized version of the usual Hodge filtration on $H_{dR}(X)((u))$, where $u$ is a formal variable of degree $2$ (which of course enforces the $2$-periodization).

Now we are missing an important ingredient in the usual Hodge theory, which is the integral lattice $H_{B}(X,\mathbb{Z})$. My understanding of the literature is that we expect there to be some construction, at the level of $DG_{\mathbb{C}}$-categories, that will produce such a lattice, and moreover, that Blanc´s topological $K$-theory is meant to be a candidate such. Now I presume that one is meant to reconstructthe integral Hodge structure on the $2$-periodized cohomology of a variety in the particular case of $Perf$, hence the following confusion.

**Question**. How does this account for the fact that there are varieties $X,Y$ with equivalent categories $Perf(X)\cong Perf(Y)$ and yet with non-isomorphic $\mathbb{Z}$-Hodge structures on their cohomology? (For example an Abelian variety which is not isomorphic to its dual provides such a pair.)

I presume the point is that one cannot produce the individual cohomology $H^{1}(A)$ plus its integral Hodge structure, only $H^{odd}((u))$?

**Edit** it is quite possible that everything above should be phrased rationally instead of integrally, my apologies if this is indeed the case.

Comment: When you say Blanc's $K$-theory is a candidate for a lattice what is the analogue of this for usual varieties? Wouldn't $K$-theory land in $H^{p, p}$ and thus generally have the wrong rank (and it wouldn't even hit the odd degrees)?

Comment: @lkx his K theory doesn't produce alg K theory for Perf (X) but top K theory of X_{an} as indeed it would otherwise be in type (p,p) and that it would give even a Q lattice in this would be Hodge conjecture. I believe I should have phrased everything rationally in fact, my apologies. See 1.21 and 1.22 of Kontsevich Lefschetz memorial talk for more info

Comment: The statement about K theory landing in type (p,p) is about only K_0, no?

Comment: @David yes certainly odd K theory will land in odd cohom